# Lubuntu 19.04 Battery Percentage Applet?

Tags: lubuntu, battery, widgets, panel-applets

Is there anyway to get my battery panel applet or widget to display percentage?

After dumb fidgeting (removing applet icon repositories) the battery applet is gone and instead it shows a settings symbol but still responds as a battery panel applet? Any help would be great.

The battery indicator is glitchy, at times I have to toggle show icon so that it actually states my batteries current status. Again any help would be great. I'd prefer not to have to reinstall lubuntu.

Comment: Lubuntu 19.04 is using a new Desktop, LXQt, instead of LXDE, and LXQt is not as mature and well-developed as LXDE. Do you have the same problem when you boot from a Lubuntu 18.04 LiveUSB? Please click [edit] to reply; please don't use Add Comment and instead use [edit].

Comment: Oh that explains it. Does the previous distro 18 or something use LXQT or LXDE. There are a lot of things subtly different in 19.04, as you say no as mature. No, this issue just sort of arose. I believe it has something to do with the panel icon theme. When I switch back to the built in battery icon, it is normal. The error occurs when I want to use icons from theme. However, in both cases the icons don't show a percentage symbol, and that option is not in the power settings.

Comment: LXQt was introduced in Lubuntu 18.10, is used in 19.04 and will be used in future releases, as per https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Lubuntu-18.10-LXQt

Comment: Thanks, any thoughts on how I may be able to get my battery applet image back when using other icons or themes?

Comment: when I do something like that, I go through the desktop and panel and note each of the items and where they came from, then go back to the default configuration and reinstall/reconfigure. I wish I had something better to tell you.

Comment: The battery applet is default. So it came installed? It is at its default configuration currently.

Comment: Is there anyway to reinstall the lxqi power manager safely?